# Good way to keep iPad clean?

Tags: ipad, screen

I don't have a case or screen protector just yet for my iPad. What is a cost effective way to keep the screen clean and remove fingerprints?

Comment: look at the gorgeous device, don't touch it :)

Comment: Don't make fingerprints. In South Korea people use sausages as styli because when it's cold those people use gloves. If you just use sausages you won't get any fingerprints on the screen, only sausageprints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yesterday I was using mine in a meeting, and a guy next to me said, "What do you use to wipe the screen down?"

I said, "My shirt." And I demonstrated my super-fancy wipe-the-screen-on-my-shirt maneuver I've worked out.

It's cheap, and it works. It's not exactly high class, but whatever.

Comment: I do too, but shirts only move the fingerprints, not remove them.

Comment: Hm. Maybe we're wearing different brands? Or I'm more shirt-aggressive than you are? I get mine squeaky clean with a little application of shirt.

Comment: "but shirts only move the fingerprints, not remove them." as long I can MOVE them outside the screen, I'm happy!

Comment: @balexandre--right! My shirt moves the fingerprint off the screen, and onto the shirt.

Comment: @Dan Ray - Some times, the shirt will not absorb the oil, but merely, "bunch it up" into highly visible streaks and finger patterns.

Comment: @Moshe - You clearly need more absorbant and geek-friendly shirts.

Comment: @Dan Ray - Yes, clearly.

Comment: Ever got the dirty ipad dust on your clean white shirt? :)

Comment: I use the shirt method too, but its effectiveness really varies. If it doesn't work, try your pants. (:

Answer (score 20):

Use the [Fingerspoo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ratio/4504477859/) iPad wallpaper and you won't notice fingerprints anymore.

[image]

Comment: lol... forget the iklear crap and just use this.  looks way more convenient :P

Comment: Got some nice feedback from people on this wallpaper. It looks absolutely filthy!

Comment: We need a high res version of this wallpaper!

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive! :D http://f.cl.ly/items/143J1w111U0j2p1g1p0I/iPad_fingerpaper_2048x.png

Answer (score 9):

Use a micro fiber cloth, like the ones used for cleaning glasses. Works for my touch screen devices all the time and needs no extra liquids or any other fancy gear.

Comment: I used to use that, until I lost the one that came with my iMac. The others aren't nearly as good.

Answer (score 3):

I LOVE the [iKlear](http://www.klearscreen.com/) products.  I spilled hot tea all over my MacBook Pro about 3 weeks after I bought it.  There were streaks of tea all over the screen and external case.  Luckily I was using a moshi keyboard cover which kept the liquid out of the keyboard area and probably saved my machine.

After I completely tore it down to make sure there was no internal damage, I tried cleaning the screen with a microfiber cloth and a small amount of water.  It worked alright but I could still see the streaks and even fingerprints and keyboard marks when I held the screen up to a light.  So I spent some time researching the best external cleaning solution and iKlear seemed to be held in high regard.

I got [this kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001W2WSIC) from Amazon and it's truly amazing how well the solution and cloths work to clean the glass screen.  The tea streaks and every other little smudge and bit of goo came off like magic.  Literally takes about 15 seconds to clean the screen to a mirror finish.  It works very well on the aluminum case and keyboard as well.

I also use it on my iPod Touch and Motorola Droid.  Since the iPad is made out of the same stuff as the MBP and the iPod, I highly recommend this stuff.  You spent all that money on your iPad, i think it's worth an additional 20 bucks or so to get a good cleaning solution.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Almost every Apple product except the iPad seems to come with a microfibre cloth, which I would recommend you use.
2. If you have a case for your iPad, I have seen some people buy a regular microfibre cloth and keep it in the case. Maybe even cut it to about 1/4 the size for portability.
3. The Apple store actually sells little microfibre cloths. They are pretty expensive though and are VERY small.
4. Use your shirt.

Comment: iPhone 4 and iPod Touch (4th gen) does not come with any :(

Comment: iPhone 3GS didn't either. Ever since iOS devices switched to the oleophobic screen, they seem to have stopped supplying us with cloths.

Comment: `google.com` -> `define: oleophobic` -> `surfaces, by contrast, repel oils. The new 3GS iPhone, for example, features a touch screen with an oleophobic polymer film designed to resist fingerprints.`

Comment: @balexandre: right, and I missed it the first days, but then I noticed that the oleophobic surface coating works quite well. I transport the iPhone 4 in my trouser's front pockets and when I take it out the screen is nicely polished.

Comment: Is that a microfiber cloth? Oh, hehe I use it to lay my iPod on when it's syncing so the backside doesn't scratch. Didn't know it was for cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

I just use wet wipes. Gets chocolate off too

Comment: Chocolate covered iPad? Sounds delicious! Mmmm...

Answer (score 2):

I have quite a few microfiber cloths around the house that I use for detailing cars, and I usually keep one of those out (that hasn't been used on the car) to wipe my iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

In Belgium, we don’t have “real” Apple Stores yet, but we do have [Switch](http://switch.be/), which is the official Apple reseller in our country.

Anyway, they sell [this iClean product](https://monsterstore.com/products/monster-iclean-screen-cleaner-1?_pos=1&_sid=9161ddd4d&_ss=r) which can be used to clean your Mac. Guess what? It also works fine for iOS devices. It comes with a microfiber cloth included and it works really well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wash your hands!

Of course you would have to do it every 10 minutes or so... Or maybe just every 2 or 3 hours, if you work in a cold environment and don't sweat - different than hot Brasilian weather. =(