# Is there a proper way to clean the iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone, screen, accessories, macos

Is there a particular proper way to clean the iPhone's glass, oleographic coated, screen in order to maintain its luster?

Comment: Screen protector? It seems like it would be either/or for any particular setup.

Comment: Is my question doesn't fit here or needs revision?

Comment: Take a look at my edit (and adjust accordingly if I missed your point). I improved the question to be Apple-specific. Also, take a look at this [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/good-way-to-keep-ipad-clean): it may be helpful for you, and provide the info you are looking for. [Or this one has some good info](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6746/what-substances-i-can-use-to-clean-the-touch-sensitive-screens-like-iphone-ipad).